# Laravel Select Menu / Dropdown

Tags: list, laravel, select, populate

I am using the following code:

```
<select onchange="javascript:location.href = this.value;">

<option value="" selected>-- Show Genre --</option>

@foreach ($genres as $genre)
<option value="{{ URL::route('tracks.order', array('order' => 'name', 'by' => 'asc', 'genre' => $genre->name )) }}">{{ $genre->name }}</option>
@endforeach

</select>
```

The $genres is populated using the following code in my controller:

```
$genres     = Genres::lists('name', 'id');
```

I was wondering if I could use a code like below instead of the foreach? I think I should be able to, but I have no clue on how to change the code to work with my code above.

```
{{ Form::select('genre', array('default' => '-- Select Genre --') + $genres, '') }}
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
$genres = ['default' => '-- Select Genre --'] + Genres::lists('name', 'id');
```

In the view:

```
{{ Form::select('genre', $genres, Form::old('genre')) }}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I meant, sorry for being unclear. I would like to know if it's possible to have the {{ Form::select with this: <option value="{{ URL::route('tracks.order', array('order' => 'name', 'by' => 'asc', 'genre' => $genre->name )) }}">{{ $genre->name }}</option> ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible :-)